# watson conversation - slack bot, textformatting

Tags: node.js, slack, watson-conversation, watson, botkit

I am having trouble formatting the slackbot responses. The slactbot is connected with watson conversation through botkit (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware). Thanks a lot

My ultimate goal is to format a JSONArray as a list in the response. But I couldn't find anything about it. I can't even output a newline with '\n' or '\\n'. On the Watson Dashboard, I would output something like this:

I notice that you shop for: $e_list.join('\n')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set this "\n" inside your code to works. Like:

```
response = "Lets see here...\n" + \
           "I've found these recipes: \n"
```

So, inside the Watson, A subtle error that can occur here is to use single quotes instead of double. That also has the effect of rendering the newlines as `\n`, than, you'll need to set with `"` and add the `\n` inside your context variable, like:

```
Here's a list I made just for you: <? $s_list.join('') ?>
```

**And inside your JSON Advance, see my example:**

```
{
  "context": {
    "s_list": [
      "onion",
      "\n",
      "olives"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Here's a list I made just for you: <? $s_list.join('') ?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

**Obs.:** The best idea is use code for did this and doesn't generate more work. Like this example from one IBM Developer using Watson conversation inside slack. Check [here](https://github.com/boxcarton/watson-recipe-bot/blob/master/souschef/souschef.py#L57).

**Obs II.:** I try added the \n inside each value from array and the output inside slack seems like: `onion\nolives` and does not recognize the `\n`, I'm not sure about the reason, but, probably another IBM Developer Specialist can explain more about that. But, maybe this is because is one array and not one String, check this [slack question](https://github.com/cleentfaar/slack/issues/21) about that.

**Image inside slack:**

[image]

Comment: Double quote doesn't really work inside watson
I have something like this: "Here's a list I made just for you:  <?$s_list.join("\n")?>" But it's giving error